# Submitting Form Using PHP with Dynamic Number of Buttons

Tags: php, forms

I have a form in PHP that contains a dynamic number of buttons. To generate the buttons, the program loops through the array $sections and each button is named substr($elementOfSections, 2).

Below is the code for submitting the form.

```
if (!empty($_POST)){

foreach ($sections as $item){

if(isset($_POST[substr($item, 2)])){ 

//This is where the processing occurs, but this statement is never run even if substr($item, 2) is the name of the button pressed.

}
}
}
```

Are there any ideas as to why this code is not being run?

Thank you.

Below is the code for the button generation (inside a form).

```
foreach ($sections as $item){

        if(substr($item, 0, 2) == "H?"){

        echo "<h4 name='" . substr($item, 2) . "'>" . substr($item, 2) . "</h4><hr class='gallery'>";      

        }

        if(substr($item, 0, 2) == "I?"){

        echo "<div class='imageContainer'><img class='image' src='" . substr($item, 2) . "' width='200px' height='200px'>&nbsp;";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='" . substr($item, 2) . "' class='deleteButton' value='Delete Image'></div>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: how do the generated buttons look like?

Comment: Try to `echo` the contents of `substr($item, 2)` for each loop, to see if the indexes are the proper ones. Are you sure that you're not doing something wrong with `substr()`?

Comment: When I var_dump substr($item, 2) both immediately after the button is made and in the loop, I get exactly the same result. However, when I var_dump $_POST[substr($item, 2)], I am told that substr($item, 2) is an undefined index.

Comment: `var_dump(substr($item, 2))` inside the loop (AKA, after the post-data is submitted) and `var_dump($_POST)` at the same point (and give us the results). I've tried reproducing your code, and it all works fine for me.

Comment: What is the contents of `$sections`?

Comment: ^Yes, the content of $sections was the problem. The array elements had dots (.) inside of them, which were replaced with underscores(_) in the array $_POST. Thank you.